# Add a Storyboard in a existing XIB Project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I use in my project only xib files. Now i need a static tableview for a settings view. I want to combinied xib and one storyboard(for the tableview).

I add a storyboard with one viewcontroller in my projekt. After than i add a identifier(SettingsView) for this viewcontroller. the following code is executed when the button was pressed:

```
SettingsView *CustomViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsView"];
[self presentModalViewController:CustomViewController animated:YES];
```

My Application crashed when i push the setting button:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SettingsView''

Comment: Did you set Storyboard identifier "SettingsView"?

Comment: I set the identifier of the viewcontroller(which is located in the storyboard).
Identifier: Storyboard ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you added the StoryBoard ID as follows in the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: Storyboard name is exactly "Storyboard"?

Comment: yes the name is exactly.I tested it now with a empty new project. here it works. but not with my old projekt.

Comment: i have a solution. I've compared the two projects and found a rule under the 'Build Rules' with the name Interface Builder Rule. I delete  it. thats work fine. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard and individual  view controller that you are attempting to instantiate,  names have match exactly. Otherwise, the rest of what you are doing is correct from what I can see.

Comment: names are exactly set :( do you have another ideas?